# How to use prim algorithm to traverse cells in a rectangular array in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, multidimensional-array, tree-traversal

in a rectangular array, I need to obtain a path consists of a series of ones starting from a given starting point (cell) in which to be the longest. I made a simple search of what are the suitable search algorithms to implement such a task and found that the prime algorithm is the most preferable technique.
Is it actually "Prime Algorithm" or other?

I tried using standard recursive based on Dijkstra's algorithm  but I could not get the correct path.

The following code is for the windows form application, some times it output a correct results and sometimes not:

```
namespace AUV_Topology
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;


        /* Class Cell */
        /*****************************************************************************************************************************/

        public class Cell
        {
            public int row { get; set; }
            public int col { get; set; }
            public int value { get; set; }
            public Boolean visited { get; set; }
        }

        /* Class EnumCell  */
        /*****************************************************************************************************************************/

        public class EnumCell : IEnumerator<Cell>
        {
            public EnumCell() { }

            public EnumCell(int startRow, int startCol, List<List<Cell>> graph)
            {
                this.row = startRow;
                this.col = startCol;
                this.numberOfRows = graph.Count;
                this.numberOfCols = graph[0].Count;
                this.graph = graph;
            }

            public enum XY
            {
                Y = 0,  //row
                X = 1   //col
            }

            public enum LOCATIONS : byte
            {
                TOP_LEFT = 0,
                TOP_MIDDLE,
                TOP_RIGHT,
                LEFT,
                RIGHT,
                BOTTOM_LEFT,
                BOTTOM_MIDDLE,
                BOTTOM_RIGHT,
                END,
                INVALID
            }

            public List<List<Cell>> graph { get; set; }
            public int row { get; set; }
            public int col { get; set; }
            public int numberOfRows { get; set; }
            public int numberOfCols { get; set; }

            //offsets are in same order as enum location as y-offset(row), x-offset (col)
            private List<List<int>> offsets = new List<List<int>>() {
                    new List<int>() { -1, -1 },
                    new List<int>() { -1, 0 },
                    new List<int>() { -1, +1 },
                    new List<int>() { 0, -1 },
                    new List<int>() { 0, +1 },
                    new List<int>() { +1, -1 },
                    new List<int>() { +1, 0 },
                    new List<int>() { +1, +1 }
                };
            public LOCATIONS position { get; set; }

            public EnumCell GetEnumerator()
            {
                return new EnumCell(row, col, graph);
            }

            object IEnumerator.Current
            {
                get {
                    return Current;
                }
            }

            /* Class Current Cell  */
            /*****************************************************************************************************************************/
            public Cell Current
            {
                get {
                    try {
                        // move to first valie postion
                        for (LOCATIONS location = position; location < LOCATIONS.END; location++) {
                            if ((row + offsets[(byte)location][(int)XY.Y] >= 0) && (row + offsets[(byte)location][(int)XY.Y] < numberOfRows) &&
                                (col + offsets[(byte)location][(int)XY.X] > 0) && (col + offsets[(byte)location][(int)XY.X] < numberOfCols)) {
                                position = (LOCATIONS)location;
                                int newRow = row + offsets[(byte)location][(int)XY.Y];
                                int newCol = col + offsets[(byte)location][(int)XY.X];
                                return graph[newRow][newCol];
                            }
                        }
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    }
                }
            }

            public Boolean MoveNext()
            {
                Boolean results = false;
                for (LOCATIONS location = ++position; location < LOCATIONS.END; location++) {
                    int y = offsets[(byte)location][(int)XY.Y];
                    int x = offsets[(byte)location][(int)XY.X];
                    if ((row + y >= 0) && (row + y < numberOfRows) &&
                        (col + x > 0) && (col + x < numberOfCols)) {
                        if (graph[row + y][col + x].value == 1) {
                            position = (LOCATIONS)location;
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            public void Reset()
            {
                position = LOCATIONS.TOP_LEFT;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
            }
        }

        /* Class Graph  */
        /*****************************************************************************************************************************/
        public class Graph
        {
            public Graph(int[,] graph)
            {
                this.graph = new List<List<Cell>>();
                for (int row = 0; row < graph.GetLength(0); row++) {
                    List<Cell> newRow = new List<Cell>();
                    this.graph.Add(newRow);
                    for (int col = 0; col < graph.GetLength(1); col++) {
                        Cell newCell = new Cell();
                        newRow.Add(newCell);

                        newCell.row = row;
                        newCell.col = col;
                        newCell.value = graph[row, col];
                        newCell.visited = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            public List<List<Cell>> graph;
        }

        /* Class SpanningTree  */
        /*****************************************************************************************************************************/
        class SpanningTree
        {
            public static Graph graph = null;
            public static SpanningTree root = new SpanningTree();

            public static int counter = 0;

            public int row { get; set; }
            public int col { get; set; }
            public int length { get; set; }
            public List<SpanningTree> children { get; set; }

            public SpanningTree() { }
            public SpanningTree(int startRow, int startCol, int[,] graph)
            {
                SpanningTree.graph = new Graph(graph);
                RecursiveTree(root, SpanningTree.graph.graph[startRow][startCol]);
            }

            public int RecursiveTree(SpanningTree parent, Cell currentCell)
            {
                int length = 0;
                int maxLength = 0;
                parent.row = currentCell.row;
                parent.col = currentCell.col;

                graph.graph[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].visited = true;

                EnumCell enumCell = new EnumCell(currentCell.row, currentCell.col, graph.graph);
                foreach (Cell cell in enumCell) {
                    if (!cell.visited) {
                        SpanningTree newBranch = new SpanningTree();
                        if (parent.children == null) parent.children = new List<SpanningTree>();
                        parent.children.Add(newBranch);
                        length = RecursiveTree(newBranch, SpanningTree.graph.graph[cell.row][cell.col]);
                        if (length > maxLength) maxLength = length;
                    }
                }
                graph.graph[currentCell.row][currentCell.col].visited = false;

                parent.length = maxLength;
                return maxLength + 1;
            }

            public static void OrderHighLow(SpanningTree parent, int level)
            {
                if (parent.children != null) {
                    parent.children = parent.children.OrderByDescending(x => x.length).ToList();
                    foreach (SpanningTree child in parent.children) {
                        OrderHighLow(child, level + 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            public static void Print(SpanningTree parent, int level, int chromosomeNum)
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/TreeParser.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
                    sw.WriteLine("------------------- Chromosome : {0} -------------------", chromosomeNum);
                    Print(parent, level, sw);
                    sw.WriteLine("---------Longest----------");
                    PrintLongest(parent, level, sw);
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }

            private static void Print(SpanningTree parent, int level, StreamWriter sw)
            {
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                sw.WriteLine("{0}Level : '{1}', Row : '{2}', Col : '{3}', Length : '{4}'", new string(' ', 4 * level), level, parent.row, parent.col, parent.length);
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                if (parent.children != null) {
                    foreach (SpanningTree child in parent.children) {
                        Print(child, level + 1, sw);

                        if (child.length == 0) {
                            sw.WriteLine("||,,,,,,Branch {0},,,,,,||", counter);
                            level = 0;
                            sw.WriteLine("{0}Level : '{1}', Row : '{2}', Col : '{3}', Length : '{4}'", new string(' ', 4 * level), level, root.row, root.col, root.length);
                            counter += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public static void PrintLongest(SpanningTree parent, int level, StreamWriter sw)
            {
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                sw.WriteLine("{0}Level : '{1}', Row : '{2}', Col : '{3}', Length : '{4}'", new string(' ', 4 * level), level, parent.row, parent.col, parent.length);
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                if (parent.children != null) {
                    PrintLongest(parent.children[0], level + 1, sw);
                }
            }
        }

}// end name space
```

I made call in the main form:

```
 int tt = 0;

 foreach (int[,] graph in rectArrays)
 {
     new SpanningTree(indexesX[tt], indexesY[tt], graph);
     SpanningTree.OrderHighLow(SpanningTree.root, 0);
     SpanningTree.Print(SpanningTree.root, 0,tt);
     tt++;
 }
```

Here is the latest results : [Debug](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mpudwhpwhtojlif/AADyUanpA-e7m4JBxF7THw6ja?dl=0)

**Problem 1**

Sometimes the path not as long as expected i.e. some cases (cells) not included while it should be!, sometimes the path contains cells with value zero, and sometimes it move from a cell to another cell while they are not adjacent to each other!.

**Problem 2**

When I use a big matrix such as 9 x 9 or above; I got the following:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: You  will need a [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes : "Backtracking can be applied only for problems which admit the concept of a "partial candidate solution" and a relatively quick test of whether it can possibly be completed to a valid solution" ??

Comment: You seem to visit all the cells. Shouldn't you restirct the visits to cells with value 1? `if (!cell.visited && cell.value == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `RecursiveTree` replace the condition

```
if (!cell.visited)
```

by

```
if (!cell.visited && cell.value == 1)
```

This restricts the search to cells with value = 1 as required.

---

Your algorithm is rather complicated and entangled. Also, the naming makes it difficult to guess what things do. For instance, it is not clear what `EnumCell` enumerates. The name suggests that it is a kind of universal enumerator; however, `MoveNext()` returns only positions with `value == 1`. Why is there a variable `results` which is always `false`? Why is the logic split between `MoveNext()` and `Current`? `Current` should only return the value found in `MoveNext`. If `MoveNext` works correctly, no other logic should be required in `Current`. There are a lot of other such oddities in your code. C# has a [yield return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) statement which makes writing an enumerator much easier.

Try to simplify your code and debug it.

I implemented a backtracking solution that returns all solutions with the maximum path length. Except for setup and printing the result, there is no other logic involved:

Declarations:

```
private int[,] _world;
private bool[,] _visited;

[DebuggerDisplay("Coord({Row}, {Col})")]
private struct Coord
{
    public Coord(int row, int col)
    {
        this.Row = row;
        this.Col = col;
    }
    public readonly int Row;
    public readonly int Col;
}
```

Backtracking algorithm (call `Find` on a valid starting point of a path):

```
// Returns a list of paths of maximum length consisting of lists of coordinates.
private List<List<Coord>> Find(int row, int col)
{
    _visited[row, col] = true;
    var allResults = new List<List<Coord>>();
    for (int i = Math.Max(0, row-1); i <= Math.Min(_world.GetLength(0)-1, row+1); i++) {
        for (int j = Math.Max(0, col-1); j <= Math.Min(_world.GetLength(1)-1, col+1); j++) {
            if (!_visited[i, j] && _world[i, j] == 1) {
                List<List<Coord>> result = Find(i, j);
                allResults.AddRange(result);
            }
        }
    }
    if (allResults.Count == 0) {
        // This is an end-point of a path. Create the new path with current coord.
        // We construct the paths backward.
        allResults.Add(new List<Coord> { new Coord(row, col) });
    } else {
        // Keep only longest results
        int maxLength = allResults.Max(p => p.Count);
        for (int i = allResults.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (allResults[i].Count < maxLength) {
                allResults.RemoveAt(i);
            } else {
                // Prepend current point to path.
                allResults[i].Insert(0, new Coord(row, col));
            }
        }
    }
    _visited[row, col] = false;
    return allResults;
}
```

Note that the full result tree exists only on the call stack, but not as an explicit data structure. The paths (coordinate lists) are created from the path end-points backwards to the starting point.

---

With this world

```
private int[,] _world = new[,] {
    { 0, 1, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 0, 1 },
 };
```

For the starting coordinates (row = 0, column = 1) my solution prints (the printing routine itself is not shown):

```
Result #1, Length = 7
| ||1|| ||·|
| ||2|| ||·|
| ||4||3|| |
|5|| || ||·|
|6||7|| ||·|

Result #2, Length = 7
| ||1|| ||·|
| ||2|| ||·|
| ||4||3|| |
|5|| || ||·|
|7||6|| ||·|
```

If you comment out the section discarding shorter results, you can see that there are 8 possible paths (2 of length 5, 4 of length 6 and 2 of length 7).

Comment: Thank you, but what about its time complexity ?

Comment: I did not calculate the time complexity, but since I only investigate valid paths, I think it is optimal. I think it depends on the complexity of the path system itself. Whether the code is efficient is a completely different aspect.

Comment: I've made this modification and passed different array each time then I've got stackoverflow problem at the first line in the method find :  // Returns a list of paths of maximum length consisting of lists of coordinates.
        private List<List<Coord>> Find(int[,] _world, int row, int col)

        {

Comment: How big are your worlds? Probably the numer of possible paths grows exponentially (or even faster?) with the world size. Especially if the density of "ones" is high. Since the `Find` method marks the current location as visited and calls itself recursively for non visited locations (`if (!_visited[i, j] && _world[i, j] == 1)`), the recursion must stop at some point. can you given an example of a concrete world (plus start coordinates), where this happens?